# Count and move files by pattern

Tags: linux, command-line, batch-rename, globbing

I have many epub files I'm trying to organise into folders. All of my files named following the same pattern "Author - Name (Year).epub".
What I'm trying to archive is to count files by authors and move them to folder named after author if number of books is more then 2 (for example).

For example, for following files:

```
Willis, Connie - [Oxford Time Travel #1] - Doomsday Book (1992).epub
Willis, Connie - [Oxford Time Travel #2] - To Say Nothing of the Dog (1997).epub
Willis, Connie - [Oxford Time Travel #3] - Blackout (2010).epub
Willis, Connie - [Oxford Time Travel #4] - All Clear (2010).epub
Wilson, Robert Charles - Julian Comstock - A Story of 22nd-Century America (2009).epub
Wilson, Robert Charles - [Spin Saga #1] - Spin (2005).epub
```

All books by Connie Willis must be moved to "Willis, Connie" folder since their count is more then 2, while books by Robert Wilson shall be untouched.

I feel really lost and don't know where to start with this.

Comment: You may get answers that do this in one step, but I think an approach by splitting into simpler steps is also possible: (1) detect authors and create directories; (2) move every file to a matching directory (it may be sane to merge steps 1 and 2 though); (3) detect directories with two or less files and move the files back to the main directory; (4) detect empty directories and remove them. // Can you perform any of these steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three-step solution. `cd` to a directory where the files are, and then:

1. This will move each file to corresponding subdirectory:

   ```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "* -*.epub" \
      -exec bash -c '
          mkdir "${1%% -*}" 2>/dev/null; mv -n -- "$1" "${1%% -*}"/
      ' bash {} \;
   ```

   `"${1%% -*}"` is a part of `"$1"` up to the first  `-` (space+minus). We expect sometimes the subdirectory already exists; `mkdir` will then fail, it's OK.
2. This will detect subdirectories with two or less files and move all their content (back) to the current working directory:

   ```
   find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \
      -exec sh -c '
         [ $(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "\n" | wc -l) -le 2 ]
      ' sh {} \; \
      -exec sh -c '
         find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec mv -n -t ./ -- \{\} +
      ' sh {} \;
   ```

   Change the `-le 2` fragment to adjust the number. You may wonder why I tell `find` to print newlines instead of filenames (default behavior). This is because `wc` is a text tool, possible newlines in filenames will break my logic. Explicitly printing exactly one newline per file fixes this issue.
3. This will remove empty directories:

   ```
   find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -empty -delete
   ```

   It should work even without `-empty` because `-delete` (like `rmdir`) will delete a directory only if it's empty. However in that case I would like to suppress expected error messages telling me the given directory is not empty. Doing this with `2>/dev/null` would also prevent me from seeing unexpected error messages though. Hence the `-empty` anyway.

Run these step-by-step or build a script. It's advised to backup your directory structure beforehand (e.g. `cp -lr my_directory my_directory_backup`) just in case. Some options I used are non-POSIX, these may not work for you. Also if you already have any subdirectories, my solution may mangle them; adjust it to your needs then.